# Mysql Crostab query

Tags: mysql, crosstab

There are few tables to store contents and categories. Contents and categories are mapped in many to many relationship.

A category can have many  contents.

A content can be included in many categories.

Therefore I have created content_cat_xref table to map those tables.

category table - id, name, etc

content table - id, name, type_code(read_it, play_it, prove_it, watch_it)

content_cat_xref - content_id, category_id, etc

I wanted to display categories with content types and count of contents for each content type as follows.

[image]

But I'm getting as follows.

[image]

My query is as follows

```
select 
ccx.category_id, 
IF(count(c.id) > 0, "True", "False") as Sections_with_content,
(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'READ_IT') THEN count(c.id) ELSE 0 END) as "READ_IT",
(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'WATCH_IT') THEN count(c.id) ELSE 0 END) as "WATCH_IT",
(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'PLAY_IT') THEN count(c.id) ELSE 0 END) as "PLAY_IT",
(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'PROVE_IT') THEN count(c.id) ELSE 0 END) as "PROVE_IT",
count(c.id) 
  from content_cat_xref as ccx left outer join content as c
  on ccx.content_id = c.id 
  group by ccx.category_id, c.type_code
```

If anyone have this kind of experience will be helpful for me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not group by `c.type_code` because it results in the various types to be grouped into separate records. The whole point of the conditional counts is to work on the entire overall group (in this case `category_id`) and return only the relevant counts.

UPDATE

You also need to change the way you do the conditional counts. The condition must be within the count() (or sum()) function, not outside of it, since you want the results to show in all cases. So, instead of

```
(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'READ_IT') THEN count(c.id) ELSE 0 END) as "READ_IT"
```

have

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.type_code = 'READ_IT') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "READ_IT"
```

Explanation: The `case` statement returns the value `1` if the condition is matched, and return `null` if it is not. `Count()` function counts all non-null values. Change all the other fields' expression based on the above example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Then it will show the total count under wrong type code. Can you please help me to retrieve relevant count in this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your follow-up question.

Comment: Hmm, I think I got it, I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Many Thanks. It works fine. One question. Why we use NULL instead of 0 here. THEN 1 ELSE NULL END

Comment: I explained this in the last paragraph of the answer.